# How do you cache reports or webpages that take a long time to generate?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

In the interest of saving time on my website, I need to cache a copy of a report on the site so it can be loaded quickly when users click the report button, instead of being generated on the spot every time  the user clicks the button.

Is there a preferred mechanism to use to store the report (it is a few figures and google charts)?

I have thought about it and I think a way to do it would be running a script (php or perl) and acquiring all the variables on a daily basis.
Then every time a user clicks the report button, it uses the stored variables to display data and generate the Google charts.

Would this be a decent solution or are there standard practices(maybe caching) that are better methods for saving time for the user?

Comment: mysql will keep results in a query cache, but it sounds like you want an application cache. Lots of options here [is a simple example in Php](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php)

Comment: What are your options? Can you access/change your server configuration? You could do this by storing the collected data into a database table, store data into a file, set up a caching mechanism on your server...

Comment: Thanks, so there are 2 options caching the returned SQL results or application caching. The DB tables are very unstructured, they are basically stored as JSON objects, so will that affect my decision? Or no influence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution sounds perfect to me, assuming the information from the report only needs to be fetched on a timer.  You could create a cron job that runs the report generating script and writes its output to `report-file.html`.  When users click "Report," just link them to this file.

You could also give users the option to regenerate the report and simply overwrite report-file.html each time.  You could even keep multiple copies of the report files for various dates.